# array manipulation in java using arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to solve one of the following interview problem :

1. Declare an array/list consisting of 26 alpha values, one for each letter of the alphabet.
2. Iteratively scan the list for vowels, removing each vowel from this first list and putting it on a second list.
3. Concatenate all elements of each list into two scalar variables (one for vowels and one for consonants), while also adding a comma between consecutive elements.
4. Print the values of the two variables on the screen.

I did the first part as follows:

```
public static void main(String args[]){




 List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
    Collections.addAll(strings,"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z");

    for (String str : strings)
    System.out.println(str);

}
```

I think I may not have understood the problem properly, the second point is talking about two lists where as in the first part, it only talks about creating one list of alphabets. Please let me know if I haven't understood something from the problem? Does combining values into two scalar variables as mentioned in third point makes sense?

Comment: I think you have to print `[(b,a), (b,e), (b, i) .... (c,a) .... (z,a) ....]` from lists `[a,e,i,o,u]` and `[b,c,d,f,....z]`

Comment: Actually, @anjibman could be correct.

Comment: Hmm, I am kind of confused with the scalar variable terminology used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From googling, I've found that a scalar variable is a variable that [only has one value at a time.](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/16441/scalar)

I believe that part 2 assumes that you create another `ArrayList` object to hold the vowels so at part 4 you should have two strings: one that contains all the consonants and one that contains all the vowels.

edit: Can't comment because I'm a new member.
In this case a scalar variable would just be a `String` object.

Comment: I am getting two lists after part 2. So, how can I combine all the elements of list1 which has vowels and list2 which has consonants into two scalar variables? I am confused here what does that actually mean.

Comment: Like I said, a scalar variable is a variable that contains _only one_ value. So objects like `List`s, `Set`s or any other type of collection are not scalar variables because they hold more than one value. Primitive types and `String` are scalar variables because they contain only one value.